# PHP get letters between two letters

Tags: php

I have two PHP dynamic variables that returns two letters based on a SQL query and for this example I will use a two random fixed letters:

```
$firstletter = "F";
$lastletter = "A";
```

I need to return all the letters in between first and last letter as an array so I can loop through them. For this example it should return F,E,D,C,B,A

Any ideas how i can do this?

Comment: what is the string .. does that contain only one A and F

Comment: Return all the letters from what? The database? A string? There's not enough to answer here. Add some more code

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, the example should return F,E,D,C,B,A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) will do this:

```
<?php

var_dump(range('F', 'A'));
```

> ```
> array(6) {
>   [0]=>
>   string(1) "F"
>   [1]=>
>   string(1) "E"
>   [2]=>
>   string(1) "D"
>   [3]=>
>   string(1) "C"
>   [4]=>
>   string(1) "B"
>   [5]=>
>   string(1) "A"
> }
> ```

Comment: Forgot that worked xD And to @Ahmed, it also works backwards as your example `range('F', 'A')` :)

Comment: The answer misses to reverse the array if firstletter > lastletter in alphabetical order - so I would say it's not yet completely corr

Comment: @MichaelLihs, thanks for that - I read right past that part. As martindilling mentions, it's simple enough to flip the order of the arguments. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$array = range('A', 'F');
print_r($array);
```

for reverse values :

```
$array = range('A', 'F');
print_r(array_reverse($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need all the alphabets between two given letters. 
you can use range to get that.
e.g. $letters = range('f', 'a');